# Endianness problem in C when pass by reference 32/64 bit

Tags: c, endianness

I am struggling with an endianness problem in below example.
In this main() passes address of 32 bit integer and myfunc() receives it in 64 bit.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(uint64_t *b)    
{    
    printf("%llx\n", *b);    
if ((*b & 255) == 127)    
   printf("\n It works\n");    
else    
    printf("\n Not working\n");    
}

main()    
{    
uint32_t a = 127;    
    printf("\n%lx\n", a);
    myfunc(&a);
}
```

It works correctly on little endian platform(Windows).

```
7f
28ff780000007f
```

It works

But it fails on big endian(AIX).

```
7f
7fdeadbeef
```

Not working

I think when we pass the address of 32 bit and receives in 64bit, on big endian platform it receives in the other 32 bits. But I am not sure.
Please help me to understand what is happening behind this. i cant correctly write the first line of program here.

Many Thanks
Ann

Comment: Wovv! it soo cool. the forum automatically included the file stdio.h, and corrected the syntax of stdint.h(which I couldnt do earlier)

Comment: No, sleske edited your post to correct the formatting. Unfortunately, the markdown software is not *that* smart yet. There are instructions on the right when you edit your posts explaining how to format code. All you have to do is indent each line a minimum of 4 spaces. You can also select it all and click the `{}` button in the toolbar, which will format a block as code automatically.

Comment: You can thank sleske for doing that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you code triggers undefined behavior. You allocate a 32-bit variable `a` and then (in `myfunc()`) try to use it as if it was 64-bit - of larger size, so you effectively try to access outside a legally allocated variable. This can cause whatever consequences and your program just can't work right because what you're trying to do makes no sense from the C Standard point of view.

Comment: But we can assign value of a small size variable to larger size variable. In the above case if we pass by value, it will work correctly. It goes wrong only when pass by reference on big endian machine. Thanks,

Comment: @user646403: Yes, you can do that when you pass by value. But when you pass by reference you trigger undefined behavior. It just happens to produce the results you expect on LE.

Comment: So if you have time could you please explain me in the above code how the bytes are stored/passed/received on big endian and little endian platforms.

Comment: @user646403: On LE lower bits are stored at lower addresses, on BE - at higher addresses. So on LE the lower bits of both 32-bit and 64-bit variables will reside in the first byte and when you try your trick the called code reads from the initialized part of the "variable". On BE the lower bits of 64-bit variable will be stored at "variable start + 8 bytes" address but the lower bits of 32 bit variable will be stored at "variable start + 4 bytes", so the called code will try to read from the uninitialized part of the "variable".

Comment: Maybe I should clarify what happens in that code. What you do is, you're lying to the compiler (I'd actually be surprised if you didn't recieve a big fat warning). The signature of myfunc tells the compiler that myfunc will recieve an (abstract!) address to a piece of memory holding a 64 bits long integer. However you pass it the address of a only 32 bits long variable, but myfunc doesn't know about this (there's no dynamic type system in C). So myfunc tries to access 64 bits of data, where there are only 32 bits well defined.

Comment: You should also know, that C never passes parameters by reference. All parameters to a function are passed by value. In the case of a pointer the pointer's value is passed. A pointer's value allows for accessing some part of memory, namely the one the pointer points to. But it would be foolish and wrong to think that the value of the pointer must be some physical or virtual address in the CPUs address space. Pointer values are only bound by the requirements of pointer arithmetic and that the value 0 always refers to the nil/invalid pointer.

Comment: It just happens that addresses in CPU address space in 99.9% of all cases fill the requirements of C pointers and so most implementations use memory addresses as pointer values. But they may as well use some lookup values to be translated by the runtime system.

Comment: Thanks all for your help... Finally I understood it clearly. we are passing address of 32 bit to the function. so the 4 bytes are stored in address a, a+1, a+2, a+3. On LE platforms LSByte is at a. But on BE platform LSByte is at a+3. In myfunc it receives the address a. Since it is 64 bits. 8 bytes are a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4, a+5, a+6, a+7.(Actual data is a to a+3). On LE platforms LSByte is at a. And it has correct data at a. But on BE its LSByte is at a+8. a+8 contains garbage value. So it is processing on garbage value.

Comment: @user646403: It works with garbage on both LE and BE, but on LE the `&255` extracts a byte from an initialized part of the variable, while on BE it extracts a byte from an uninitialized part.